# PHP SQL multiple rows in single entry

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning how to work with PHP and SQL and I'm facing a small trouble.

How do I ADD and SELECT a multiple line entry from SQL using PHP.

```
        $queryy = [
           $idSala = addslashes ($_POST['idSala']),
           $organizer = addslashes ($_POST['organizer']),
           $date = $_GET['date'],
           $time_start = $_GET['starthour'],
           $time_end = $_GET['endhour'],
           $subject = $_POST['subject'],
           $description = $_POST['description'],
           $attendee = $_POST['invitee1']
           ];
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO logs ". "(toIdSala,organizer,date,hourstart,hourend,subject, description, attendee) ". "VALUES('$idSala','$organizer','$date','$time_start','$time_end','$subject','$description','$attendee')";

        mysql_select_db('scheduler');
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

        header('Refresh: 3; URL=sendmail.php?' . http_build_query($queryy));
```

If I use multiple lines on 'description', when I SELECT from that table I don't get multiple lines back. 'description' is a TEXT type column.

**Example**

Form filled in 'description' as following:

```
We are going to talk about topics:
1 - PHP & SQL basics
2 - great discussion over here
```

SQL query replies a single line:

```
We are going to talk about topics: 1 - PHP & SQL basics 2 - great discussion over here
```

Can anyone help me?
I understand this isn't a hard issue to solve. I've been looking for answers to this question but it's hard to find something related when most of "multiple lines or rows" tutorials and question are related to other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably printing the result from `description` in a html. Try calling `echo nl2br($description);` or surround it with `<pre>` tags and it will probably appear in multiple lines.

Comment: That worked out very well. I was printing using the usual: echo "<td>" . $description . "</td>" method. Thank you Angel.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. You could as well accept my answer, in order to help other people with the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a while loop to fetch all results from the database. So after `$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );` you will need:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval)) {
    // $row holds the results
}
```

Additionally (as always...), please consider using the newer mysqli-functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this while displaying the data

```
htmlentities($description);
```